# Y axis value of the swiper slide stored in array and y value retrieved at slide chance

Tags: angular, swiper.js

i want to create three swiper slides, here i want to save the scrolled height, i.e. the y value in an array, so that when the slide is changed, the respective slide can be rendered again at the previously closed position using the height saved in the array. however, this does not work. i am able to save the values in the array, but not render the slide at the previously saved height.

html:

```
<ion-header >

</ion-header>


<ion-content >


  <swiper-container 
    #swiper
    (afterinit)="swiperReady()"
    (slidechange)="swiperSlideChanged($event)"
    [virtual]="true"
   
    >

    <swiper-slide >

    
        <!--  some code -->



  
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide >
      
        <!--  some code -->

    
    </swiper-slide>
    <swiper-slide >


        <!--  some code -->
     

    </swiper-slide>
  </swiper-container>


    <div style="height: 20px">

    </div>


</ion-content>
```

ts

```
import { Component, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';



import Swiper from 'swiper';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss'],
  standalone: true,
  imports: [IonicModule],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class Tab2Page {



  @ViewChild('swiper') swiperRef: ElementRef;
  swiper?: Swiper;

  scrollPositions: number[] = [0,0,0];


 
  private currentIndex: number = 0;


  selectedIndex: number = 0;



  


  constructor() {
    
  }



   async ngOnInit() {

    this.swiperReady()

 }




  swiperReady() {
    this.swiper = this.swiperRef?.nativeElement.swiper;
    console.log("SWIPER "+ this.swiper)
  }



async  swiperSlideChanged(event: any) {





    //console.log(event);

    const swiper = this.swiperRef.nativeElement.swiper;

    //swiper.slide

    const previousIndex = swiper.previousIndex;
    const currentIndex = swiper.activeIndex;

  
    //console.log( " offset top "+     currentSlideElement.offsetTop     +   "slides   " +currentIndex);

    console.log(swiper.offsetTop)
    //console.log(document.querySelector('swiper-container').offsetTop);

    
    if (typeof previousIndex === 'number') {
        this.scrollPositions[previousIndex] = swiper.touches.currentY;
    
    }

    console.log(this.scrollPositions)


}


async loadPosition(){
  
  const swiper = this.swiperRef.nativeElement.swiper;
  const currentIndex = swiper.activeIndex;
  swiper.touches.currentY = this.scrollPositions[currentIndex]
/*   swiper.scrollTop({
    top: this.scrollPositions[currentIndex]
  }) */
  
 

}


}
```